# Unity cube with black edges

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

I want to get an cube with black edges:
[image]

Yet I'm unable to even google an tutorial how to make such thing. I was able to find some tips about shaders, but those are a black magic for me, I can't even begin to think how to use those in order to get what I want.
Any ideas how to make such simple (?) effect in an simple way?

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time and perhaps this is not THE solution, but after all it does "work":

1. I created an PNG file in Paint - just white square with black border, as simple as can be. Than just copy the file into unity assets - doesn't matter where exactly.
2. In unity I created new material, and set my PNG file as "Albedo" of this material.
3. Last thing is to set this material as the cube material, and - depending on the png file border thickness, the cube should more or less look linke on the image above.

Still - If someone does know a better solution, I'm open for suggestions, as my solution does not really scale well, and the edge thickness can be changed only by replacing the png file rather than change one parameter.